# XCode 5, analyser warning

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

When I've try to Analyse .m, I've got strange warning:

> warning: Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1
>   (owning) retain count is expected

on the line

```
return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

the code is:

```
- (NSNumber*)index
{
  return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
}
```

Similar code with string is passed correctly.

```
- (NSString*)ss
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1];
}
```

Did I miss something with NSNumber constructor, or is it bug in Analyser?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the warning with your code. Is this your exact code? Which Xcode/SDK do you use? Naming the method `newIndex` causes that warning as expected, but not `index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C methods naming is critical in determining their memory management.

Methods whose name starts with `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` are expected to return an object with a +1 retain count, whereas everything else should return autoreleased objects, i.e. with a +0 retain count, as explained in the [Advanced Memory Management Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

With this in mind, if your method is really named `index` then the analyzer is mistaken.

---

As a side note, you can take advantage of Objective-C literals for a simpler `NSNumber` creation.

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
```

can be replaced by

```
@1
```

and

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:anExpression];
```

can be replaced by

```
@(anExpression)
```

Comment: You right. My method name starts with "new". Therefore analysers expect non autoreleased object.

Comment: @IgorPchelko: Please do always copy/paste your actual code, to avoid that other people waste their time by trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the analyzer, because in both cases an autoreleased object is returned.

Note that you can simplify the code with the new `@` syntax as follows:

```
- (NSNumber*)index
{
  return @1;
}
```

You need parentheses if you must return an expression, like this:

```
- (NSNumber*)index
{
  return @(value1 + value2); // Same as [NSNumber numberWithInt:value1 + value2];
}
```

Comment: return @1; - produce same warning. Looks like it's Analyser's bug.

Comment: @IgorPchelko Yes, this definitely looks like a bug in the analyzer: `index` does not fall in the [method family](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15747674/335858) that needs to return a +1 ref count, so it should not give you the warning.